# UpdateLayeredWindow and DrawText

Tags: winapi, mfc

I'm using UpdateLayeredWindow to display an application window. I have created my own custom buttons and i would like to create my own static text. The problem is that when i try to draw the text on the hdc, the DrawText or TextOut functions overwrite the alpha channel of my picture and the text will become transparent. I tried to find a solution to this but i could not find any. My custom controls are designed in such way that they will do all the drawing in a member function called Draw(HDC hDc), so they can only access the hdc. I would like to keep this design. Can anyone help me?  I am using MFC and i would want to achieve the desired result without the use of GDI+.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old post ... but I just had this very same problem ... and it was driving me CRAZY.

Eventually, I stumbled upon this [post](https://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.gdi/browse_thread/thread/c0227ad779269215?hl=en%E1%8E%B8dca24283912b) by Mike Sutton to the microsoft.public.win32.programmer.gdi newsgroup ... from almost 7 years ago!

Basically, the DrawText (and TextOut) do not play nicely with the alpha channel and UpdateLayeredWindow ... and **you need to premultiply the R, G, and B channels with the alpha channel**.

In Mike's post, he shows how he creates another DIB (device independent bitmap) upon which he draws the text ... and alpha blends that into the other bitmap.

**After doing this, my text looked perfect!**

Just in case, the link to the newsgroup post dies ... I am going to include the code here. All credit goes to Mike Sutton (@mikedsutton).

Here is the code that creates the alpha blended bitmap with the text on it:

```
HBITMAP CreateAlphaTextBitmap(LPCSTR inText, HFONT inFont, COLORREF inColour)
{ 
    int TextLength = (int)strlen(inText); 
    if (TextLength <= 0) return NULL; 

    // Create DC and select font into it 
    HDC hTextDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL); 
    HFONT hOldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(hTextDC, inFont); 
    HBITMAP hMyDIB = NULL; 

    // Get text area 
    RECT TextArea = {0, 0, 0, 0}; 
    DrawText(hTextDC, inText, TextLength, &TextArea, DT_CALCRECT); 
    if ((TextArea.right > TextArea.left) && (TextArea.bottom > TextArea.top))
    { 
        BITMAPINFOHEADER BMIH; 
        memset(&BMIH, 0x0, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)); 
        void *pvBits = NULL; 

        // Specify DIB setup 
        BMIH.biSize = sizeof(BMIH); 
        BMIH.biWidth = TextArea.right - TextArea.left; 
        BMIH.biHeight = TextArea.bottom - TextArea.top; 
        BMIH.biPlanes = 1; 
        BMIH.biBitCount = 32; 
        BMIH.biCompression = BI_RGB; 

        // Create and select DIB into DC 
        hMyDIB = CreateDIBSection(hTextDC, (LPBITMAPINFO)&BMIH, 0, (LPVOID*)&pvBits, NULL, 0); 
        HBITMAP hOldBMP = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hTextDC, hMyDIB); 
        if (hOldBMP != NULL)
        { 
            // Set up DC properties 
            SetTextColor(hTextDC, 0x00FFFFFF); 
            SetBkColor(hTextDC, 0x00000000); 
            SetBkMode(hTextDC, OPAQUE); 

            // Draw text to buffer 
            DrawText(hTextDC, inText, TextLength, &TextArea, DT_NOCLIP); 
            BYTE* DataPtr = (BYTE*)pvBits; 
            BYTE FillR = GetRValue(inColour); 
            BYTE FillG = GetGValue(inColour); 
            BYTE FillB = GetBValue(inColour); 
            BYTE ThisA; 
            for (int LoopY = 0; LoopY < BMIH.biHeight; LoopY++) { 
                for (int LoopX = 0; LoopX < BMIH.biWidth; LoopX++) { 
                    ThisA = *DataPtr; // Move alpha and pre-multiply with RGB 
                    *DataPtr++ = (FillB * ThisA) >> 8; 
                    *DataPtr++ = (FillG * ThisA) >> 8; 
                    *DataPtr++ = (FillR * ThisA) >> 8; 
                    *DataPtr++ = ThisA; // Set Alpha 
                } 
            } 

            // De-select bitmap 
            SelectObject(hTextDC, hOldBMP); 
        } 
    } 

    // De-select font and destroy temp DC 
    SelectObject(hTextDC, hOldFont); 
    DeleteDC(hTextDC); 

    // Return DIBSection 
    return hMyDIB; 
}
```

Here is the code that drives the CreateAlphaTextBitmap method:

```
void TestAlphaText(HDC inDC, int inX, int inY)
{ 
    const char *DemoText = "Hello World!\0"; 
    RECT TextArea = {0, 0, 0, 0}; 
    HFONT TempFont = CreateFont(50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "Arial\0"); 
    HBITMAP MyBMP = CreateAlphaTextBitmap(DemoText, TempFont, 0xFF); 
    DeleteObject(TempFont); 
    if (MyBMP)
    {
        // Create temporary DC and select new Bitmap into it 
        HDC hTempDC = CreateCompatibleDC(inDC); 
        HBITMAP hOldBMP = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hTempDC, MyBMP); 
        if (hOldBMP)
        {
            // Get Bitmap image size
            BITMAP BMInf;
            GetObject(MyBMP, sizeof(BITMAP), &BMInf); 

            // Fill blend function and blend new text to window 
            BLENDFUNCTION bf; 
            bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER; 
            bf.BlendFlags = 0; 
            bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 0x80; 
            bf.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA; 
            AlphaBlend(inDC, inX, inY, BMInf.bmWidth, BMInf.bmHeight, hTempDC, 0, 0, BMInf.bmWidth, BMInf.bmHeight, bf); 

            // Clean up 
            SelectObject(hTempDC, hOldBMP); 
            DeleteObject(MyBMP); 
            DeleteDC(hTempDC); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: +1 good to know this solution. i thought it is impossible to use gdi drawtext in layered window before.

Comment: got it working with using COLORREF white = 0x00FFFFFF; COLORREF black = 0x00000000; auto x = ::SetTextColor(hTextDC, white); auto y = ::SetBkColor(hTextDC, black); also used CString intext {inText} (GetLength) instead of LPCSTR, thanks a lot for this