# Draw semitransparently in invisible layered window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

My goal is to have a fullscreen overlaying invisible "canvas" on which I can draw using win32's various drawing functions.

The way I am currently attempting it is this:

```
WNDCLASSA myclass = { 0 };
myclass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc3;
myclass.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(0);
myclass.lpszClassName = "MyCanvas";
myclass.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(0xFEEDBEEF);
myclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
RegisterClassA(&myclass);
```

...

```
HWND wnd = CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, "MyCanvas", 0, WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, screen_width, screen_height, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(wnd, 0xFEEDBEEF, 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

Although this serves as a canvas, hours of googling later, I am still unable to draw on it semitransparently.

I have added a screenshot of what my program is currently displaying as I am writing this. What I would like to be able to do is, for example, make the black box in the top right corner (drawn with `Rectangle`) semitransparent so as to reveal the stackoverflow page content below it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309914/updatelayeredwindow-and-drawtext) is a question I found that I was hopeful about, but the resulting text is just a blended combination of the background color `((COLORREF)0xFEEDBEEF)` and text color. Other things I have found have either just made the element fully invisible, done nothing at all, or required some library like MFC. I want to **only use win32** functions if at all possible, as I would like to be able to achieve the highest FPS possible.

I do not care if this doesn't work on all Windows versions as long as it does on 7 up to 10.

[image: Current state of the problem]

Comment: Here ya go - have a look at this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13550/XCPClock-CodeProject-Clock I won't post code here, since I'm too lazy to review and condense the code I wrote after reading it and implementing it..

Comment: @enhzflep I got super excited when I realized I had been using `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` only half correctly but shortly afterwards I realized it appears you can only have one color key (meaning, it would be impossible to both have the background invisible and have a semitransparent element at the same time). I may be wrong in this but I do not think so. :(((((

Comment: the code shown draws a circular clock-face. Parts of the rectangular window outside this circle are entirely transparent (color-keyed), while _all of the rest_ has the same level of transparency - this level of transparency can range from 0% to 100% - I.e it would be possible to make all of the green text semi-transparent (but it would all have the same level of transparency). Hope that's what you're interested in. Failing that, you have to mess around and copy the window behind yours and perform the transparency effect yourself with pre-multiplied alpha - possible, but not exactly fun. ;)

Comment: *"Other things I have found have [...] required some library like MFC."* - So then, there is your answer. MFC is a resource management wrapper around the Windows API. If you need Windows API code, just rip it from there. It's not like MFC is some magical tool that can do more than the OS provides through its API. Besides, you **can** combine color keying and alpha transparency (`LWA_ALPHA | LWA_COLORKEY`). This is a per-window attribute. You cannot confine it to a sub region, though.

Comment: What was your intent with (0xFEEDBEEF) ?  The high-order byte of a COLORREF generally must be 0 (with only very specific exceptions).

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I wanted to make the background invisible, so having it be a nonsensical brush that is impossible to actually have would ensure non-background colors don't become invisible (that is assuming it's not, say, anded by FFFFFF which I don't know). I got rid of that anyway, though. My end solution was to use `UpdateLayeredWindow` to have a fullscreen bitmap be drawn each frame.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you only need transparency for a rectangular area where all pixels either have the same transparency (aka *alpha*) value or are completely transparent, you can use [`SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540(v=vs.85).aspx) with a combination of alpha value and/or color key.

[`UpdateLayeredWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556(v=vs.85).aspx) is the way to go if you need to be able to define transparency per-pixel.

For that you have to create [memory DC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145049(v=vs.85).aspx) and select a 32bpp bitmap into it. You may use the [buffered paint API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773257(v=vs.85).aspx) to ease the task. Raymond Chen has a [blog post with a code sample](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110520-00/?p=10613) about that.

You can draw into the memory DC, but you can't use most of GDI API for that, because GDI ignores the alpha channel (transparency). I suggest using [GDI+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798(v=vs.85).aspx) which allows you to specify the alpha values.

After you have completed drawing into the memory DC, you would call [`UpdateLayeredWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556(v=vs.85).aspx) and pass that memory DC as the argument for the `hdcSrc` parameter to make the result visible on screen.

**Illustration of possible effects:**

[image: SetLayeredWindowAttributes with LWA_ALPHA]

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes( hwnd, 0, 176, LWA_ALPHA );
```

[image: SetLayeredWindowAttributes with LWA_COLORKEY]

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes( hwnd, colorkey, 0, LWA_COLORKEY );
```

[image: SetLayeredWindowAttributes with LWA_ALPHA|LWA_COLORKEY]

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes( hwnd, colorkey, 176, LWA_ALPHA|LWA_COLORKEY );
```

[image: UpdateLayeredWindow]

```
UpdateLayeredWindow( ... )
```

Note the antialiased edge of the shape and the transparency gradient in the last example. Things like that are only possible with `UpdateLayeredWindow()`.

Comment: Lots of good info, thank you. I will try and do as you say with `UpdateLayeredWindow` as soon as I can. Could you elaborate on how to use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` to affect a rectangular area?

Comment: @Lupe I have added some images for illustration.

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks a bunch! I will add the working code once I have a good example.